# window.location not working together with my function

Tags: jquery, html

I am unable to move to the next page upon submitting the form.

I have a form where the user enters their address and mobile number. There are validations and if it is valid, the details and the current date are stored in the local storage.

```
$("#deliveryform").validate({
    rules:{
      txtpostalcode:{
        required: true,
        number: true,
        minlength: 6,
        maxlength: 6,
      },
      txtaddressline1:{
        required: true,
      },
      txtmobilenumber:{
        required:true,
        number: true,
        minlength: 8,
        maxlength: 8,
      }
    },

  });

$("#paymentbtn").bind('click',function(){
    if ($("#deliveryform").valid()) {
      submitaddress();
      alert("good");
      window.location = "payment.html";

    }
 });

function submitaddress() {
var postalcode =  $("#txtpostalcode").val();
var address = $("#txtaddressline1").val() + " " +  
$("#txtaddressline2").val();
var mobilenumber = $("#txtmobilenumber").val();

var currentdate = new Date();
var dd = currentdate.getDate();
var mm = currentdate.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = currentdate.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
  dd = '0'+dd
}

if(mm<10) {
  mm = '0'+mm
}

currentdate = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd   ;

localStorage.setItem("postalcode", postalcode);
localStorage.setItem("address", address);
localStorage.setItem("mobilenumber", mobilenumber);
localStorage.setItem("currentdate", currentdate);
}
```

My html code

```
<div class="deliveryoption">

<form action="" id="deliveryform" >

<div class = "deliveryaddress">

 <div class="form-group">Enter Delivery Address</div>
<div class="form-group col-form-1">
  <input class="form-control" type="tel" maxlength="6" name="txtpostalcode" id="txtpostalcode" placeholder="Postal Code"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-form-1">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtaddressline1" id="txtaddressline1" placeholder="Address Line 1"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-form-1">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtaddressline2" id="txtaddressline2" placeholder="Address Line 2(Optional)"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-form-1">
  <input class="form-control" type="tel" maxlength="8" name="txtmobilenumber" id="txtmobilenumber" placeholder="Mobile Number"/>
</div>

</div>

<div class="form-group col-form-1"><button class="btn btn-block" 
id="paymentbtn"><b>PROCEED TO PAYMENT</b></button></div>

</div>
```

Im expecting the page to set the details into the local storage and move on to the next page "payment.html".

Comment: change window.location to "window.location.href"

Comment: didnt work, it does sets the local storage and the page refreshes after that

Comment: what exactly you looking for in your code ?

Comment: Try `window.location.href = "//payment.html"`

Answer (score 1):

use **window.location.href** = "";

> ```
> $("#paymentbtn").bind('click',function(){
> if ($("#deliveryform").valid()) {
>   submitaddress();
>   alert("good");
>   window.location.href = "payment.html";
>
> }  });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. console.log($("#deliveryform").valid()) and check if it returns true.
2. remove alert("good")
3. try use full path rather a page (eg. www.example.com/payment.html) as location

Comment: it returns true

Comment: - please use the full url (eg. www.example.com/payment.html)
- return false; after this line window.location = "payment.html";

or check with window.location.href 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **window.location.assign** instead of window.location.

```
$("#paymentbtn").bind('click',function(){
    if ($("#deliveryform").valid()) {
      submitaddress();
      window.location.assign = "https://www.yourwebsitename.com/payment.html";
    }
 });
```

Reference is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Comment: Be sure to click on help to see suggestions on how to make your answer better! You're halfway there 